# How to properly cast view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector

I'm having an issue with casting my view controllers. This is a snippet of my code in my appdelegate:

```
        InitViewController *initVC = (InitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
        VMParentVC *topVC = (VMParentVC *) initVC;
        [topVC navigateToMain];
```

What i'm trying to do is cast the rootViewController so that I am able to use a method from my VMParentVC class on it. But when I do this, i get this error:

"[UINavigationController navigateToMain]:unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Not quite sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That error means that you're calling `-navigateToMain` on an instance of `UINavigationController`, which is not what you want.

This is happening, perhaps, because your window's root view controller is a `UINavigationController` instance and the view controller you're looking for is the first view controller in the navigation stack. If that's the case you want to look at the first view controller inside the `UINavigationController`:

```
 UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController;
 *topVC = (VMParentVC *) navigationController.viewControllers[0];
  [topVC navigateToMain];
```

It would also be safer to check if the view controller is actually that kind of class that you think it should be after you pull it from the navigation stack:

```
 UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController;
 UIViewController * topVC = navigationController.viewControllers[0];

 if ( [topVC isKindOfClass:([VMParentVC class])] ) {     
      [((VMParentVC *)topVC) navigateToMain];
 }
```